# SearchView with Firebase RealTime Database is taking too long to bring results and it's expensive

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, searchview

I'm trying to get a specific user by it's mail with a searchview in my app.

I have more than 7000 users in my database and with this searchview it takes like  from 5 to 10 or 15 seconds to filter and bring data

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {

    searchQuery.startAt(s).endAt(s+"\uf8ff").limitToFirst(3).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                UserPojo user = snapshot.getValue(UserPojo.class);
                Log.i(TAG, "onDataChange: " + user.getEmail());

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    return false;
}
```

the problem is the time it takes to filter the data (from 5 to 15 seconds)

Is there anyway to filter faster with a better query ? or do I need to get all the data at first , store locally and then filter it there in client side ? any suggestions on how to approach this ?

Also I have noticed with the profiler that each search is taking from 4 to 8mb of network in order to get done, that's a lot of network use for just a simple text query.

[See network usage here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3uqv.jpg)

thanks

Comment: Hello Todd. *it takes like from 5 to* : is tested on Real device or emulator?

Comment: real device, with all the profilers test and I have implemented a lot of queries, the same result on almost all of them

Comment: I really don't know why some people downvote , since this is a real issue if Firebase is taking too much network usage over this simple problem. I just want to be informed on how it works and why this is happening, nothing else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may not have defined an index on the field you're searching on. If there is no index, the filtering cannot be done on the server. So in that case the server sends all data to the client, which does the filtering. This would explain why it takes longer than you expect: it has to send all 7000 user profiles to the client.

If this is indeed the cause of the problem, you can fix it by adding an index in your rules file. Say that you're ordering/filtering a list called `users` on a property called `email`, you'd do this by:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      ".indexOn": "email"
    }
  }
}
```

For more on this topic see the [Firebase documentation on indexing data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data).

Comment: Thanks so much Frank !